# Splunk get the response time in the log and use it for graph

Tags: splunk

I am new to splunk and I am trying to see how to get the values from the log to display on the splunk as a graph.

My search:

```
index=aws_test sourcetype=aws:ecs source=am/pm-* NOT "healthCheck" target=accounts ResponseTime
```

results:

```
Time           | Event
7/27/20        |
10:52:28.957AM | ssa=|target=am|responseTime=5180ms|type=info
---------------|-----------------------------------------------
7/27/20        |
10:55:38.977AM | ssa=|target=am|responseTime=4180ms|type=info
```

what I tried to do is to get responseTime="*" to the timechart.

Comment: do you have any sample data we can refer-to to help?

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a bit of a start, but still a ways to go.  To create a timechart you need two fields, _time and a number.  _time is built-in so that's easy.  We just have to extract the number for responseTime using `rex` and we'll be good to go.

```
index=aws_test sourcetype=aws:ecs source=am/pm-* NOT "healthCheck" target=accounts ResponseTime
| rex "responseTime=(?<responseTime>\d+)"
| timechart span=1h avg(responseTime)
```